# Apache 2 VHost - www.domain.com works but domain.com goes to registrar

Tags: apache, vhosts

I am using the following VHOST:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    #Basic setup
    ServerAdmin administrator@mydomain.com
    ServerName www.mydomain.com
    ServerAlias mydomain.com

    <Directory /home/mydomain/public_html/mydomain.com/mydomain/apache/>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    LogLevel warn
    ErrorLog  /home/mydomain/public_html/mydomain.com/logs/apache_error.log
    CustomLog /home/mydomain/public_html/mydomain.com/logs/apache_access.log combined

    WSGIDaemonProcess mydomain.com user=www-data group=www-data threads=20 processes=2
    WSGIProcessGroup mydomain.com

    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/mydomain/public_html/mydomain.com/mydomain/apache/mydomain.wsgi
</VirtualHost>
```

It's working fine when I visit www.mydomain.com, but mydomain.com is taking me to my domain registrars holding page (I am using their nameservers for simplicity.) Is this a problem with my vhost file or something I need to configure with the registrar?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add mydomain.com A record in DNS

Add www.mydomain.com as cname in DNS

In vhost configuration change the entry like this:

ServerName mydomain.com

ServerAlias www.mydomain.com

It will work.

Comment: www.mydomain.com ought to be an A record with www in its name field and the mydomain.com IP in its value field. Since that's often the default setup a DNS change may not even be necessary to fix this issue because the problem is mainly the swapped ServerName and ServerAlias setting.